# RegExp inside of switch case inside of debounce not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with a VueJS app that takes a search input and I am then going to query different APIs based on the term. My first regexp is only supposed to match on numbers that are up to 7 digits. However, it is matching on anything.

I'm assuming the debounce and the switch/case statement is causing some confusion - but I'm not sure.

In the end, I'm going to need to have 6 or 7 different regexp tests that I will be checking against so I need to get this to work.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Sample JS:

```
Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: []
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch(search, loading) {
      loading(true);
      this.search(loading, search, this);
    },
    search: _.debounce((loading, search, vm) => {
      console.log('search term is '+ search);
      var regex1 = /([0-9]){0,7}/;

      switch(true){
        case regex1.test(search):
          console.log('we have a number '+ search);
          break;
        default:
          console.log('default case '+ search);
          fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${escape(search)}`).then(res => {
            res.json().then(json => (vm.options = json.items));
            loading(false);
          });
          break;
        };
    }, 350)
  }
});
```

Codepen example:

https://codepen.io/thindery/pen/xeqBGx?editors=1010

Console shows the output. Try to search for a regular word like "vue" or "library". Those are triggering the number regexp for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `/([0-9]){0,7}/` will let any string pass, because it allows zero digits without any restrictions on the rest of the string.

So add `^` and `$` anchors to your regex. You don't need the parentheses, and `\d` is `[0-9]`:

`/^\d{0,7}$/`